# Is it there a way to call a Parsley validator inside another one?

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

## EDIT:

I tried this without success:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('date', {
    validateString: function(value, format) {
        if (! value) {
            return true;
        }

        var date = moment(value, format, true);
        return date.isValid();
    },
    priority: 256,
    messages: {
        en: 'It must be a valid date with format %s',
        it: 'Deve essere una data valida nel formato %s'
    }
});

window.Parsley.addValidator('datebeforenow', {
    validateString: function(value, format, parsleyField) {
        console.log("value", value);
        if (! value) {
            return true;
        }

        var $elem = parsleyField.$element;
        $elem.attr(parsleyField.options.namespace + 'date', format);
        $elem.removeAttr(parsleyField.options.namespace + 'datebeforenow');
        
        $elem.parsley().whenValidate().then(function () {
            $elem.attr(parsleyField.options.namespace + 'datebeforenow', format);
            $elem.parsley().reset();
            var date = moment(value, format, true);
            console.log("date", date);
    
            return date.isBefore(moment());
        }).always(function () {
            $elem.attr(parsleyField.options.namespace + 'datebeforenow', format);
            console.log("$elem", $elem)
        });
    },
    priority: 255,
    messages: {
        en: "Date must be before now",
        it: "Inserire una data precedente a quella attuale",
    },
});
```

`date` message is correctly displayed if you enter an invalid date, but if you enter a valid date after the current date, no message is displayed. I tried also to set a lower priority to `date`.

---

## ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have created this Parsley validator:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('date', {
    validateString: function(value, format) {
        if (! value) {
            return true;
        }

        var date = moment(value, format, true);
        return date.isValid();
    },
    priority: 256,
});
```

and I have this other validator:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('datebeforenow', {
    validateString: function(value, format) {
        if (! value) {
            return true;
        }

        var valid_date = Parsley._validatorRegistry.validators.date.validateString(value, format);

        if (! valid_date) {
            return true;
        }

        var date = moment(value, format, true);

        return date.isBefore(moment());
    },
    priority: 256,
});
```

I hoped that `Parsley._validatorRegistry.validators.date.validateString(value, format);` called the other validator and the field will show up the error message of `date` validator, so I don't need to add both the validators. But the error message does not appear.

What's the correct way to call a validator inside another one?

Answer (score 0):

Parsley has no mechanism to have dependencies between validators. It has been thought so that validators are independent.

Answer to original question:

Since you want different error messages, the only correct way to handle this situation with Parsley is to activate the different validations (in your case both `date` and `datebeforenow`).

A quick way could be to execute `$('[data-parsley-datebeforenow]').attr('data-parsley-date', '')` after your forms are generated.

Comment: I want to add this validators as `extra` in parsley.js itself, so I can't do what you suggest. See https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/1296/files#diff-e2583240a4bf145909dea4a3f8b238c8R13

Comment: I know. I don't see your point or why you couldn't do what I suggest, sorry.

Comment: Because I want it as the default for the validators. The code you suggest must be added by the developer that uses my `extra` validator in its own code. On the contrary I want that the validator `datebeforenow` and the other one calls `date` without any developer extra code.